# How to update Django variable passed through context using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I've spent quite some time trying to solve this, I've seen a bunch of solutions but I just can't seem to wrap my ahead around this.

So basically, I have this view in which I pass an array I want to display in the template and an index (arr in the view), which is the index of the array that I currently want to display. Meaning that when I first load the page the index will be 0 and I will display the first element of said array. Then, I wanted to update this index variable (by clicking the X button) so I can display the next elements (2, 3 and 4) of the array without reloading the page. I figured I can do this using an Ajax Query however, I can't get seem to get the value to update in the template.

Thank you in advance!

**results.js**

```js
(function () {
 //automatically called as soon as the javascript is loaded
 window.addEventListener('load', main);
}());

function update_display_counter(e, display_counter){
 const $csrf_token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').attr('value');
 display_counter++;
 $("#arr_counter").val(display_counter);
 $.ajax({
  headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': $csrf_token },
  url: "/establishments/results/",
  dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          'arr_counter': display_counter,
  },
  success: function (json) {
   console.log(json)
  display_counter = json['sucess']
  display_counter = parseInt(display_counter)
  $("#arr_counter").val(display_counter);


    },
      });
 return display_counter;
}

function main(){
 const acceptBtn = document.getElementById('accept_btn');
 const rejectBtn = document.getElementById('reject_btn');
 let display_counter = 0;
 acceptBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  window.location.href = 'establishments/';
 });
 rejectBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  display_counter = update_display_counter(e, display_counter);
 });
}
```

**view.py**

```
def handle_results(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    arr_counter = request.POST.get('arr_counter')
    print("THIS IS: ", arr_counter)
    return JsonResponse({"sucess": arr_counter})
else:
    try:
        coordinates = request.session['coordinates']
        del request.session['coordinates']
        display = handle_places_search(request, coordinates)
        handle_transactions(request, display)
    except request.ConnectionError as e:
        print("Connection error: ", str(e))
    except request.Timeout as e:
        print("Timeout Error: ", str(e))
    except request.RequestException as e:
        print("RequestException Error: ", str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: ", str(e))
    return render(request, "results.html", context={"display": display, "arr": 0})
```

**results.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% block styles %}
        <link href="{% static 'main_tanto_faz/styles/index.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'results.js' %}"></script>
    <p hidden id="arr_counter">{{arr}}</p>
</head>
<body>
    <button type = "button" id="accept_btn">O</button>
    Testing: {{arr}}
    <button type = "button" id="reject_btn">X</button>
</body>
```

Comment: your view doesn't actually do anything on a POST except sending by "success". And your javascript doesn't do anything in the success function except log the response to console. Just update your view to return whatever content is required and your javascript success function to manipulate the html to change whatever is needed in the document based on the response.

Comment: @dirkgroten Hey. I've edited my answer. I made the changes you suggested but I still can't get the template {{arr}} value to update. Is there something I'm still doing wrong?

Comment: where's the `<div>` with id "are_counter" in your template? Your code looks good on first glance, must be small detail. Check in your browser dev tools the request/response (network tab) and set a breakpoint inside your success function to go through it step by step.

Comment: @dirkgroten Do I need the div? I wanted {{arr}} to remain hidden to the user but still update the value. How can I do that with the div? And do I set to set the element with value = {{arr}} ? I think that's what I'm finding confusing atm. Thank you for your patience

Comment: `$("#arr_counter").val(display_counter);` is already setting the value for a DOM element with id "arr_counter." you can use any div (<input type="hidden">) and for any div you can always set the css to hidden (`display:none;`). But yes, it needs to be a DOM element, could be <p>.

Comment: @dirkgroten Ok. I think I'm starting to get it. One last question would be, using $("#arr_counter").val(display_counter); to set the value to the <p> DOM (I have it in the template as <p hidden id>, how can I then access and use it's value?

Comment: $("#arr_counter").val() is the current value. Now I see your <p>, not sure that's a good idea, especially if it's in <head>. Anyway, any div can have a val(). If you want to actually put the value in the contents of the div, then you shouldn't use val() but html() or text() but that's only relevant if you're going to display it.

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't need to display the index number as is, but I do need to do something like this in the template {{ display.display_counter}} so I can show the contents of the array to the user. So I should just use html to change the display_counter and then display it inside that div like above?

Comment: why doesn't your view return the actual value to show to the user then? Otherwise you need to already have all the elements of the array in your HTML (as hidden divs or inside a javascript array variable) and with your js, pick the right element to display.

Comment: @dirkgroten I do have all the elements of the array passed through context (see the views.py function), the only thing I really wanted to change was the second value passed in the context, arr: 0.

Comment: What I’m saying is that your js doesn’t have access to `display` so you either need to output all the possible values in your template as html divs (hidden) and your js then Unhides the one with the correct index. Or which would be more logical, return the value in your POST and not in the original view.

Comment: @dirkgroten I finally figured it out, thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine. If you check `$("#arr_counter").val()` you'll see the value of the div was most likely set correctly.

Note that browser developer tools don't always reflect `value` changes directly in the source code, so you won't see `<p hidden id="art_counter" value="3">0</p>` in your browser dev tools.

Also, having your `<p>` in `<head>` rather than `<body>` is an odd choice. It will never be displayed. If you just want to keep track of a variable in javascript, just use a `var` (of `let` in more modern ECMAScript) and adjust its value:

```
// In your template, initialise the var with a value from the context
var counter = {{ arr }};  
// or if it's a string
var counter = "{{ arr }}";

// then when the you receive a new value through ajax: 
counter = response.data.counter;
```